# Selenium Grid: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have two machines, one with all the stuff I need (Eclipse + TestNG  +scripts) and the other one with just browsers installed.
I use Selenium Grid 2.35.0.

Everything seems to be fine except the problem that very often I get this error:
`Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.`

Scripts are not complicated at all, I run them one-by-one, so it just happens randomly. I don't think it's because of the browser.
Any idea/fix?
If you need more info I'm here.

Comment: I see this issue as well, via Behat/Selenium tests.  The browser window is open, and the script was driving the session just fine until it suddenly dies with the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I get that error is when I manually close the browser myself.  I would verify that the machine withe the browsers is stable.

It could also be due to calling driver.quit() and not instantiating another driver (I haven't ever done this, so I don't know what error this throws)

Answer (score 0):

I notice this error as well but ONLY when using Selenium grid (using 2.35 but 2.38 exists now)

When I run locally I don't get error communicating with the browse but typically it can happen when there is a bug with your setup and teardown code (maybe one of your classes creates an instance of your browser before your setup function gets called)

Answer (score 0):

See [How to close child browser window in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839075/selenium-webdriver-driver-close/16839863)

ensure to call `driver.close();` on every popup / new windows / new tab you open during the test (after switching to it using `driver.switchTo()`)

and to call `driver.quit();` at the end of the session (generally in @AfterClass annotated method)