# Page is not loaded in Selenium WebDriver using Python on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am using Python 3.5 on a Windows computer. When I run this code on my Mac it works perfect, no issues what so ever.  But when I bring the code to my Windows computer it doesn't work.

Basically a blank page is shown instead of the home page. I don't get any error messages.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()

print(cookies)
```

Once I close the web browser I get this message in the shell:

`"The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

From what I've been able to find online (most is for Java) it looks like I may need to setup a profile?  Is this correct and could anyone help with this?

Comment: I am using newest version of Selenium and Firefox.  Also using Windows 8

Comment: Did you try close the brower using selenium?

driver.close(); or driver.quit();

See that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839075/how-to-close-child-browser-window-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858

Comment: It might be happened due to incompatibility of the version of WebDriver & FF

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your client doesn't have the fix for the new switch to launch the gecko driver:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/c76917839c868603c9ab494d8aa0e9d600515371

Make sure that you have the latest beta version installed (selenium-3.0.0b2) if you which to use the geckodriver v0.10.0 and above:

```
pip install -U selenium --pre
```

Note that you need the `--pre` flag to install the beta version.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info.  I will try to do this on Tuesday when I am back at work, I'll be sure to leave feedback.